# iOS in-app purchase count miss match

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect DAILY reports for our app shows lets say **52 purchases a day**... but according to our server logs, there was **55 purchases** processed on the same day for which the items were delivered.

How is this possible?

Our server is keeping all the original purchase receipts (all 55 of them) and even now we can re-validate all of them with the apple servers successfully.

We are using "**original_purchase_date_pst**" in the receipt to identity the date of purchase which we believe what iTunes uses when downloading the DAILY report (We did tried matching with all other "purchase_date" fields in the receipt... but with no success)

The daily report shows NO REFUNDS...

We do have "**transaction_id**" for all 55 purchases, but there is no way to match them against the DAILY REPORT.

Please help,

**UPDATE:**
Contacted Apple and got a template response (as expected)...

"Apple Sales and Trends reports are working as expected. We can’t account for any discrepancies between our reports and those of any outside reporting systems.
Let us know if you have additional questions about this information. You can reach me Monday - Friday, from 7:00 AM - 5:00 PM (PST) at 1(877)-206-2092."

I had sent them the full details... but they will not even look at it!

**UPDATE:** 
Ok, considering if its a REFUND (or REVERSAL as @Ricky suggested), how do we check which transaction was refunded? we do have all the **transaction_id** but the Apple report does't show any.

Comment: Are you tracking restore of previous purchases?

Comment: @Wain, all of these in-app items CONSUMABLE and are consumed immediately after the purchase... am guessing RESTORE is only applicable for CONSUMABLE items. Thanks

Comment: Just throwing this out there but is this possibly a timezone issue? i.e 3 purchases where made on the same day according to Apples timezone but not yours?

Comment: @sbarow, tried with different time fields in the receipt itself (not my server) and non of them matches the daily report... checked over multiple days. Its an on going issue... every day I am seeing a couple of purchases less in the iTunes Connect report than my server.

Answer (score 2):

If you confirmed that there is no **Refund**. How about a **Reversal** of an accidental purchase (eg: purchase 2 times)?

If you read **Appendix L - Newsstand Report Field Definitions** for

https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

There is a field **Sales/Return**:

```
Can be S or R. R is a refund and not a reversal.
```

It is reasonable to believe that Apple treats **Refund** and **Reversal** differently. I believe that when it is a refund, you will see a negative value under **Units** on your daily report, but for a reversal, the entire transaction might be cancelled out and not even appear on the report.

I am *unable* to confirm on that with 100% confidence, I guess you may drop an email to Apple Itunes Connect Support for more info on reading the Sales and Trends and daily report.

Added a Screen shot for **Reversal** (Apple does not mention **Refund**):-

[image]

So is the Report By Apple treat Refund and Reversal different? You have to ask Apple support.

**Add extra screen shot:-**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the link... "Sales/Return" column does not exists in our daily report for some reason... the REFUNDS are usually identified by a -ve value in the "Units" column.

Comment: This is what you can do, check with Apple if there is a **Reversal**. Because Refund and reversal are different like it says on the PDF document. See: http://www.labnol.org/software/itunes-app-store-refunds/13838/ There is a screen on the bottom by Apple Reply, Apple support mentioned about Reversal, not a Refund.

Comment: Yes, I contacted Apple and got a template response (as expected)... "Apple Sales and Trends reports are working as expected. We can’t account for any discrepancies between our reports and those of any outside reporting systems."... I have given them full details... but they will not even look at it.

Comment: Hm... then I really have no idea. From what I read from the documentation, it seems like Refund and Reversal are 2 different things. I just scared the the support personal does not understand the accounting practice for the daily report as the record for purchase and reversal might cancel each other out. So, the support might not have access to the _complete_ report that contains the reversal.

Comment: Ok, considering if its a REFUND or REVERSAL, how do we check which transaction was refunded? we do have all the transaction_id but the Apple report does't show any. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it is a Refund, you will see negative value under Units for the daily report. But for Reversal, I can not confirm 100% that it actually exists because the documentation is not clear enough. We are unable to know which transaction as Apple does not provide the information. Check the screen shot I updated above. No problem. I am glad that I am able to help. ;)