# How to reconcile financial information for in-app purchases to transactions?

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app

We have an iOS app that supports in-app purchase. When someone makes an in-app purchase we create a Sales Order and Invoice in our ERP system (Netsuite) at the relevant store list price. We record the Apple transaction ID on these ERP records. When we receive a deposit from Apple for purchases, we need to be able to create a Payment record and apply the funds to the Invoice. I.e. we need to split the Apple bank deposit into payments for each transaction.

The way we do this reconciliation for Stripe and ACH/Check payments is to match transaction level payment information to Sales Orders. This allows our finance team to properly handle accounting for fees etc. and for them to have confidence we have received payment for all orders.

However, for in-app purchase we can find no way of downloading a report with transaction level information from App Store Connect. There are only summaries available at the country level. Based on other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231352/app-store-connect-does-not-show-all-sales-why),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308993/ios-in-app-purchase-count-miss-match)) it seems that it is simply not possible to get a transaction level report available from Apple. With this limitation how can we reconcile the funds received from Apple against our transactions?